# C#/.NET webapi - Returning an exception (HTTP Status Code) From Method in Controller with List Return Type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I want to restrict access to api when token passed in header does not match value in my configuration.  I have created a custom guid in my project to prevent access to non matching token values or empty header values.

Using this setup how do I properly return a 404 or some other status from an action in a controller whose return type is a list of a specific type (used for returning JSON)?

```
  [HttpGet]
  [Route("getList")]
  public List<_Type> func([FromUri] int? value)
  {
      if (Request.Headers == null || !Request.Headers.Contains("token") || Request.Headers.GetValues("token").First() != ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["token"])
          throw new HttpException(404, "Not found");   //works but triggers a object null reference exeption
      return new List<_Type>();
  }
```

Comment: set the Response.StatusCode = 404 and throw an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("getList")]
public ActionResult func([FromUri] int? value) {
    if (Request.Headers == null || !Request.Headers.Contains("token") || Request.Headers.GetValues("token").First() != ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["token"])
        return NotFound();
    return Json(new List<_Type>());
}
```

Comment: and, for your Scenario, consider usage of [ActionFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can change return type into IHttpActionResult. Ok() method takes an object as parameter so you can pass your collection.

```
[HttpGet]
  [Route("getList")]
  public IHttpActionResult func([FromUri] int? value)
  {
      if (Request.Headers == null || !Request.Headers.Contains("token") || Request.Headers.GetValues("token").First() != ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["token"])
          return NotFound();  //works but triggers a object null reference exeption
      return Ok(new List<_Type>());
  }
```